# sort mongodb collection by date in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I’m new to mongodb and trying to figure out sorting with MongoClient in a node.js/express application.

This works in the mongo command line client:

```
db.mycollection.find().sort({"date":-1}); // displays by date, newest to oldest
```

I’m trying to achieve the same thing in my application:

```
db.collection('mycollection').find().sort({"date":-1}); //order remains the same
```

How can I achieve the same result as the first query? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, first, I'd recommend using Mongoose.  Failing that, however, the Node MongoClient puts things like sorting into the find() arguments, like so:

```
db.collection('mycollection').find({}, {sort:{date:-1}});
```